# Calling a member function of every element of a C++ vector

Tags: c++, function, vector

Suppose there is a vector of class objects.

```
vector<Object1> vec;
```

Say, `Object1` has a member function `void foo(Object2*)`.

I want to do the following:

```
for(int i=0; i<vec.size(); i++) {
    vec[i].foo(obj2);
}
```

How can this be done without using an explicit loop?

Comment: whats wrong with using a loop ?

Comment: @giorashc, always prefer an algorithm over a loop. Although, there is ranged-based for now.

Comment: @giorashc Nothing wrong. Just like there is `for_each` to apply function on elements of a vector, I wanted to know if there is some way to call a member function for every element of a vector.

Comment: @chris: That question is different from this question.

Comment: @vikaspraj, my bad, it has that specific difference to it.

Comment: @chris: what algorithm you are talking about ??? there is no logic whatsoever in his question only a matter of pure syntax

Comment: @giorashc, there are a few mentioned in the answers.

Comment: @chris look at Benj's reply in the answers

Comment: Didn't you ask the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516495/calling-a-function-on-every-element-of-a-c-vector) 20 minutes ago?

Comment: @Bhargava No, the questions are different. Please have a look again.

Comment: You answered yourself, create a function that receives the object and calls the method, and then pass this function to for_each.

Answer (score 7):

Easiest with TR1/C++11:

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>

struct Object2{};

struct Object1 {
  void foo(Object2*) {}
};

int main() {
  std::vector<Object1> vec;
  Object2 obj2;
  std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::bind(&Object1::foo, std::placeholders::_1, &obj2));
}
```

But you can also use `std::for_each` with `std::bind2nd`,  and `std::mem_fun_ref` if that's not an option:

```
std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::bind2nd(std::mem_fun_ref(&Object1::foo), &obj2));
```

Comment: Doesn't for_each count as a loop?

Comment: It's not an **explicit** loop :)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, it's an algorithm, which should be preferred over a plain loop.

Comment: @chris - A loop is a simple algorithm... and this std::algorithm is basically a loop, so where's the advantage?

Comment: @Benj - for me the advantages are: a) makes intention clearer. Mostly what I'm doing is about the data, not the control structure, which this emphasises b) I don't get nagged for calling `.end()` on the container on every iteration of the loop (some people like to complain about that) c) It's harder to make accidental typo mistakes

Comment: @awoodland - I've heard this argument before, and I think it's true in many more complicated cases.  However in the case where you want to run a method on every item in a vector, what could be clearer than looping over the vector and calling the method?  As intentions go, it's about as clear as it gets.  I can't help thinking there's a certain amount of dogma associated with the principle of using algorithms for everything.

Comment: Other C++11 versions: `std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&obj2](Object1 &o) { o.foo(obj2); });` or `for (auto &o : vec) { o.foo(obj2); }`. If anyone cares to argue that the latter is an "explicit loop" and hence "less clear" than using an algorithm, then let's hear it ;-)

Comment: *I don't get nagged for calling `.end()` on the container on every iteration* -- ouch. `.end()` is usually a *cheap* operation, and even then you can just cache the result: `for (It_t it = v.begin(), end = v.end(); it != end; ++it )`. Still, I would argue with those that nag you...

Answer (score 0):

One older style is to manually write a functor. For more complex logic this allows you to dedicate a whole class to the problem.

```
class fancyFunctor
{
  Object2* m_data;

public:
  fancyFunctor(Object2 * data) : m_data(data){}

  operator()(Object1 & ref) 
  {
    ref.foo(m_data) 
  }
}
```

Then to iteratate :

```
std::for_each(vec.begin(),vec.end(), fancyFunctor(&randomObject2));
```

Answer (score -1):

Readibility of such code isn't perfect, and it cannot be done in any simple one-line way.
It is because, the first argument of member method of some class is pointer to the object of this class, on which it will be performed.

Alternatively you can use foreach loop that comes with new C++11 standard (but it is still loop).

Comment: You'll notice my answer has a simple one line way for both C++11 and C++98/03, despite the pointer.

Comment: Yes, you are right - my bad. Didn't take into consideration C++11/tr1 binding (at first I should have read your whole post).